# Displaying Tweets from Hashtag

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter

I am trying to display all tweets with a hashtag, for example an event name. I've looked around and tried various bits of code and still no joy, the code pasted below actually worked for me about a year ago. It doesn't appear to be now.

```
<?
$feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23Mandela&rpp=100";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
foreach($xml->entry  as $id => $entry)
{
   //do what you want here,
   //some (definitely not all) available values are
   $linkToTweet = $entry->link[0]["href"];
   $linkToAvatar = $entry->link[1]["href"];
   $timestamp = $entry->updated;
   $tweet = $entry->content;
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to get the tweets with the API v1. If you go to the url provided, it says: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1." See [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview)

Comment: You have to migrate to API v1.1
and replace your search method with [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). Also note that twitter handles only json as response format

Answer (score 1):

This is how did it in my PHP project. My task was to insert 2 resent tweets by hashtag. The list of tweets must be updated automatically when somebody posted new tweet.

**1. Create Twitter App**

It could be a really long process (approval by Twitter team could long up to several days) and objectively not a topic of the question. There are a lot of examples in Google [https://www.google.com/search?q=Create+Twitter+App](https://www.google.com/search?q=Create%20Twitter%20App). The only thing I should mention is that you need to get these 4 codes at the end of the process:

- `consumer_key`
- `consumer_secret`
- `access_token`
- `access_token_secret`

**2. Download TwitterWP tool**

That's a good and small (only single `.php` file) library which allows you to make search requests to Twitter API. https://github.com/jtsternberg/TwitterWP You need only a single `/lib/TwitterWP.php` file.

**3. Include TwitterWP file into your project**

```
<?php include_once('inc/TwitterWP.php'); ?>
```

**4. Get tweets**

```
<?php
    $app = array(
        'consumer_key'        => 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
        'consumer_secret'     => 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
        'access_token'        => 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
        'access_token_secret' => 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET',
    );

    // initiate your app
    $TwitterWP = TwitterWP::start($app);
    $search = "#nasa AND exclude:retweets AND exclude:replies"; // search by hashtag #nasa and exclude all retweets and replies
    $tweets = $TwitterWP->get_search_results(
        $search,
        $count = 10,
        array(
            'result_type' => 'recent'
        )
    );
?>
```

**5. Create HTML containers**

Create containers for the tweets in your HTML and pass tweets IDs as data attributes

```
<div id="tweet_1" data-id="<?php echo $tweets->statuses[0]->id; ?>"></div>
<div id="tweet_2" data-id="<?php echo $tweets->statuses[1]->id; ?>"></div>
```

**6. Include widgets.js**

This official Twitter JS library will help us to create tweets

```
<script src='https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'></script>
```

**7. Do the magic**

Create tweets in your containers using JavaScript:

```
window.twttr.widgets.createTweet(
    document.getElementById('tweet_1').dataset.id,
    document.getElementById('tweet_1')
);
window.twttr.widgets.createTweet(
    document.getElementById('tweet_2').dataset.id,
    document.getElementById('tweet_2')
);
```